# Creating a template with default arguments based on type

Tags: c++, templates

I wanted to create a template for numerical values and for a given type I would like to provide default values for the min and max values.

I found a solution that works so far...

```
template<typename T> struct MinDefaultValue;
template<typename T> struct MaxDefaultValue;
template<typename T, usize_t MinDefault = MinDefaultValue<T>::value, usize_t MaxDefault = MaxDefaultValue<T>::value>
class NumericColumn
{
public:

public:
    NumericColumn(T *pAddress, T nDefault, usize_t nMinValue = MinDefault, usize_t nMaxValue = MaxDefault)
    {
        mAddress = pAddress;
        mDefault = nDefault;
        mMinValue = nMinValue;
    }

    bool toValue(void)
    {
        return true;
    }

private:
    T *mAddress;
    usize_t mMinValue;
    usize_t mMaxValue;
    T mDefault;
};
template <> struct MinDefaultValue<byte_t>  { static const usize_t value = (usize_t)CHAR_MIN; };
template <> struct MaxDefaultValue<byte_t>  { static const usize_t value = (usize_t)CHAR_MAX; };
```

The reason why I don't like it is, because now `Min-` and `MaxDefaultValue` is outside the class namespace, while it belongs inside it.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to define the specializations for the various types, because the parent class itself is also a template.

I changed the class to this:

```
template<typename T>
class NumericColumn
{
public:
    template<typename T> struct MinDefaultValue;
    template<typename T> struct MaxDefaultValue;

public:
    NumericColumn(T *pAddress, T nDefault, usize_t nMinValue = MinDefaultValue<T>::value, usize_t nMaxValue = MaxDefaultValue<T>::value)
    {
        mAddress = pAddress;
        mDefault = nDefault;
        mMinValue = nMinValue;
    }

    bool toValue(void)
    {
        return true;
    }

private:
    T *mAddress;
    usize_t mMinValue;
    usize_t mMaxValue;
    T mDefault;
};
```

But when I try to provide the spezialisations I get a compiler error:

```
template <> struct NumericColumn<byte_t>::MinDefaultValue<byte_t>  { static const usize_t value = (usize_t)CHAR_MIN; };
template <> struct NumericColumn<byte_t>::MaxDefaultValue<byte_t>  { static const usize_t value = (usize_t)CHAR_MAX; };

'class' : invalid or missing type parameter list
```

Comment: You're specializing `MinDefaultValue<byte_t>` for `NumericColumn<byte_t>`.      Don't you need `template <> template <>`?

Comment: What do you mean? Don't I have to provide the type in the specialization?

Comment: Now I don't know what you mean. I just guessed an came up with [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dbc7e3b56fcd44c), but you already have a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second approach isn't quite what you mean it to be. Having `MinDefaultValue` and `MaxDefaultValue` as inner template classes means that every `NumericColumn<T>` template instantiation will have a separate template class. So `NumericColumn<int>::MaxDefaultValue<int>` is a separate type from `NumericColumn<float>::MaxDefaultValue<float>`.

Maybe what you want is a simple `static const` member which you specialize for each type:

```
template<typename T>
class NumericColumn
{
public:
    static const std::size_t MinDefaultValue;
    static const std::size_t MaxDefaultValue;

public:
    NumericColumn(T *pAddress, T nDefault, 
                  std::size_t nMinValue = MinDefaultValue, 
                  std::size_t nMaxValue = MaxDefaultValue)
        : mAddress{pAddress}, mDefault{pDefault}, 
          mMinValue{nMinValue}, mMaxValue{mMaxValue}
    { }
};

template<>
const std::size_t NumericColumn<int>::MinDefaultValue = 1;
template<>
const std::size_t NumericColumn<int>::MaxDefaultValue = 10;
```

Note that if you don't define member specializations for some `NumericType` specialization, you'll get a link error when that is instantiated. Maybe that's what you want, maybe it isn't.

---

Here's a possible way to get a better error message at the expense of some brevity:

```
template <typename T>
struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
class NumericColumn
{
public:
    struct MinDefault{
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value,
                      "T does not have a minimum default defined");
    };
    struct MaxDefault{
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, 
                      "T does not have a maximum default defined");
    };

public:
    NumericColumn(T *pAddress, T nDefault, 
                  std::size_t nMinValue = MinDefault::value, 
                  std::size_t nMaxValue = MaxDefault::value)
        : mAddress{pAddress}, mDefault{pDefault}, 
          mMinValue{nMinValue}, mMaxValue{mMaxValue}
    { }
};

template<>
struct NumericColumn<int>::MinDefault {
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 1;   
};

template<>
struct NumericColumn<int>::MaxDefault {
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 10;   
};
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get an error, so the user knows that the type is not fully implemented or supported.

Comment: @Devolus cool, then this should work for you. Maybe there's a way of getting a better error than there currently is, I'll think about it.

Comment: Yes. Having a proper error message would be better, but this works as I intended it. :)

Comment: @Devolus I added a possibility for better error messages, although it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it doesn't seem to work. Now I get error messages (using Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: @Devolus hmm, it works fine in clang and gcc. Not sure what the issue would be.

Comment: Mabye it's Visual Studio 2010, because it's not fully C++11 compliant. For example, it also doesn't know `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specialize the template inside the template class.  I expect someone who knows the c++ standard better than I can chime in on that.

You could maybe use an access shim:

```
template <typename TColumn, typename T> inline T MinDefaultValue();

// specialization:
template <> inline byte_t MinDefaultValue<NumericColumn<byte_t>,byte_t> () {
   return 5;
}
```

You can probably reduce this down by putting a typedef in your column type:

```
typedef T value_type;
```

And then something along the lines of:

```
template <typename TColumn> inline typename T::value_type MinDefaultValue();

// specialization:
template <> inline byte_t MinDefaultValue<NumericColumn<byte_t> > () {
   return 5;
}
```

This then does then allow specialization of the min value for the column class type.

This will fail if there is no specialization.

Comment: You can specialize a nested template class, you just need to use `template<> template <>`.