# Default template type based on later template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, default-parameters

I have a function which creates an object and inserts it into a container. In most cases, the object type is the same as that of the container elements. Then, I don't want to have to specify the object type. But for containers holding `std::variant`, I want to be able to specify the object type as the first template parameter. Here's the non-working example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using remove_qualifiers = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
template<typename T>
using IteratorType = decltype( std::declval<remove_qualifiers<T>>().end() );
template<typename T>
using ElementType = decltype( *( std::declval<remove_qualifiers<T>>().end() ) );

template<typename E = ElementType<T>, typename T, typename ... Args>
IteratorType<T> insert( T& someContainer, Args&& ... ){
    IteratorType<T> it { someFindFunc() };
    return someContainer.insert(it, E{std::forward<Args>(args) ...});
}
```

The problem is, that the default type for `E` is based on `T`, which at this point is not declared yet. But if I change the order, then calling the function becomes awkward.

How can I make this pattern work, so that I can call the function both with and without specifying `E`?

I guess this is likely a case of not finding the right search terms. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496526/default-template-parameter-based-on-type-of-other-template-parameter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696443/deciding-a-template-type-depending-on-a-another-template-type), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852472/how-to-deduce-template-type-based-on-another-template-type), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805644/creating-a-template-with-default-arguments-based-on-type) one, and they don't appear to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why does changing the order of the template paramters make calling the function awkward?  You should be able to get rid of `E` and just use `using element_t = ElementType<T>;` inside the function.

Comment: Then it would *always* be that type. I want to be *optionally* able to specify the type, and have it deduced otherwise.
Changing the order like `template<typename T, typename E = ...,...` means that when specifying `E`, one needs to call the function as `insert<MyT<...>, E>(...)`, even though `T` is deducible. That's awkward.

Comment: What's wrong with making it e.g. `void` and having a `using RealE = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<E, void>, ElementType<T>, E>;` declaration inside the function? (or similar `if constexpr ()` if more readable)

Comment: @lorro That does not appear to answer the question.
How can I achieve that I can call the function *both with and without specifying* `E`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrap it into a class template so that you don't need to worry about specifying the type of the container.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Inserter {
public:
    Inserter(T& someContainer): container{someContainer} {}
    using IteratorType = decltype( std::declval<remove_qualifiers<T>>().end() );

    template <typename E = ElementType<T>, typename... Args>
    IteratorType insert(Args&&... args) {
        IteratorType it = container.begin(); // just for sample
        return container.insert(it, E{std::forward<Args>(args) ...});
    }
private:
    T& container;
};
```

Then,

```cpp
std::vector<std::variant<int, double>> v;
Inserter{v}.insert<int>(1);
Inserter{v}.insert<double>(1.1);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7T5vs5sz1)

Comment: You may test the other requirement (_In most cases, the object type is the same as that of the container elements. Then, I don't want to have to specify the object type._) as well: `std::vector<int> vI; Inserter{vI}.insert(1);`

Comment: Yes, they should be tested as well. The problem resides in the `ElementType`, which will be `int&` if not specified. Since `T` must be a conatiner, just use `typename T::value_type` might be fine or deal with qualifiers more carefully here. Maybe a little offtopic here. Anyway https://godbolt.org/z/63ds96ccs Works fine.

Comment: I found out that it becomes better with `E(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)`. (I changed `{ }` into `( )`.) I don't know why it helps nor whether the code does what's intended (although I believe). All this initialization stuff is still mysterious to me. I must admit that I saw yesterday a Cpp-Con-talk about initialization due to the recommendation of somebody in a comment... ;-)

Comment: FYI: my fiddling on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YE1j1Krrb)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using some sort of emplace, you should just move construction to the caller. For simplicity I'm using `push_back` instead of `insert`.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Value>
inline auto insert(T& container, Value&& value) {
  container.push_back(std::forward<Value>(value));
}
```

But let's assume you are *really* constructing the type in place.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline auto emplace(T& container, Args&&... args) {
  container.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This is possibly all you need. You can construct any type, variants as well.

```cpp
struct A {  int n; };
struct B {  int n; };

auto a = std::vector<A>{};
emplace(a, 100);

auto b = std::vector<B>{};
emplace(b, 100);

auto ab = std::vector<std::variant<A, B>>{};
emplace(ab, std::in_place_type_t<A>{}, 100); // tell the type
emplace(ab, 100); // ambigious, compile error
```

As for your specific use-case, there is no way of deducing some sort of *default type* of a variant. You always have to tell explicitly what to construct.

You can reinvent the wheel, create an overload for variants and then hide `std::in_place_type_t`. But generally this problem has been solved by the STL for any type that can be constructed in place.